# Symfony4/Doctrine - Cannot connect via SSL (DBAL Config)

Tags: mysql, ssl, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Can somebody please let me know what's missing? All %env% variables are correct. Everything worked perfectly until I enabled SSL.

Using these connection details and 'Key.crt.pem' I have no issues connecting to the database using Sequel Pro.

Error:

**{"code":500,"message":"An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [9002] SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry."}**

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: latin1
    default_table_options:
        charset: latin1
        collate: latin1_swedish_ci
    dbname:               '%env(resolve:DATABASE_NAME)%'
    host:                 '%env(resolve:DATABASE_HOST)%'
    port:                 '%env(resolve:DATABASE_PORT)%'
    user:                 '%env(resolve:DATABASE_USER)%@%env(resolve:DATABASE_HOST)%'
    password:             '%env(resolve:DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
    mapping_types:
            enum: string
    options:
        MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA : '/Path/Key.crt.pem'
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer [@sanjok Gurung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565552/sanjok-gurung)

From symfony 3.2, you can use php constants in yaml files. 
In this example, it would give:

```
options:
   !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: : '/Path/Key.crt.pem'"
```

Ref: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted it.

!php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA:

Comment: Hi please, could you elaborate on this answer.